# Refresh Lets encrypt root CA in docker container

Tags: docker, ssl, debian, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I'm running debian 9 in my docker container and today I was not able to update root certificate for Lets encrypt inside container. On host Ubuntu 20 everything worked without any my intervention, but on my debian container I was not able to get new root Lets Encrypt certificate, only recreation container from scratch helped. I tried `update-ca-certificates --fresh`, but it didn't help. Any ideas?

Due this issue request from inside container towards https services with Lets Encrypt certificate failed with "SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired", because root certificate of Lets Encrypt expired today (September 30, 2021)

Comment: Can you share more specific information ? What does the `Dockerfile` look like ? How do you update the root-cert ? How and which command do you run specifically ? Do you get any error messages ?

Comment: I tried to update with `update-ca-certificates --fresh`, seems it worked ok, no error, but still connection to https with lets encrypt didn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try first to remove the old certificate from your list in /etc/ca-certificates.conf:

```
sed -i 's#mozilla\/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt#!mozilla\/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt#g' /etc/ca-certificates.conf
update-ca-certificates --fresh
```

Comment: I was able to reproduce this error on my host and running those commands fix that problem. I was not able to test this inside docker, because I was not able to wait so long, so work around were to rebuild docker images from scratch. If I will find one more docker container with this problem, I will retest this commands from inside. But I'm pretty sure that this will help.

Answer (score 3):

Yesterday I also faced the same issue, but I'm sharing the hack things because it's production env so I have to do that immediately and my docker images are in AWS ECR. So I decided to rebuild the image that TaskDefinition has.

Just pull the docker images from ECR, create a new Dockerfile using that image

```
From <acc.docker-image:tag>
RUN sed -i 's/mozilla\/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt/!mozilla\/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt/g' /etc/ca-certificates.conf
RUN update-ca-certificates
```

Build the new docker image and pushed to the ECR, created a new revision from the TaskDefinition, and updated the latest Image.

Finally, I Updated the ECS Service with a new TaskDefintion, and my issue got resolved in 20mins.

I'm not sure about your ENV, but this simple hack things will reduce the pain and you spend time to rebuild the base image for your application.