# Curl retrieval of webpage stopped working between August and September 2021

Tags: php, docker, curl, ubuntu-18.04

I've been using a docker (20.10.4) based webserver built from php:7.0.19-apache with the docker installed curl package for the php version.  It has been working fine on a ubuntu 18.04 host machine in a php script to retrieve a web page up until now.  Now it is failing to retrieve the page; last worked in early August.  I have not changed the web server in the docker container and have not modified the code the uses the curl command.  I have verified that I can access the page using a browser. Given that, it seems like an update to either docker or the host machine OS has caused the issue.  I have no idea how to diagnose the problem.

Webserver docker file:

```
COPY config/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
        git \
    && docker-php-ext-configure sockets \
    && docker-php-ext-install sockets \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd\
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) mysqli\
#    && pecl install xdebug-2.5.0 \
    && pecl install xdebug-2.8.0 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

# Installation of Composer
RUN cd /usr/src && curl -sS http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN cd /usr/src && mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer

# Installation of tools with composer
RUN composer global require --no-plugins --no-scripts phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor
RUN composer global require --no-plugins --no-scripts squizlabs/php_codesniffer
RUN composer global require --no-plugins --no-scripts phpunit/phpunit
RUN composer global require --no-plugins --no-scripts phpunit/dbunit
RUN composer global require --no-plugins --no-scripts phploc/phploc
RUN composer global require --no-plugins --no-scripts phpmd/phpmd
RUN composer global require --no-plugins --no-scripts simpletest/simpletest

ENV PATH /root/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: *"Now it is failing to retrieve the page"*, what happens exactly? Whats the response? Any log entries?

Comment: @DarkBee. This sounds like it might apply here as the certificate for the server hosting the web page is from Let’s Encrypt. Since the web page can be accessed by a web browser on the Ubuntu based computer hosting the docker container without warning,  I think the trust is established on that system.  Now, would the docker container need something added?  If so, any reference to how that is done would be awesome.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @Definitely not Rafael Curl returns an empty string for the web page fetch.  I have not been able to find log files for curl.

Comment: @Frank See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69401972/refresh-lets-encrypt-root-ca-in-docker-container) to update the root certificate for docker

Comment: @Frank try to debug it as stated in the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php): *"Note that response status codes which indicate errors (such as 404 Not found) are not regarded as failure. curl_getinfo() can be used to check for these."*

Comment: @DarkBee  Thank you.  You identified the problem cause and provided a link to the docker root certificate fix.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Frank no worries, had the same issues on my servers