# Removing DST_Root_CA_X3 in Archlinux

Tags: ssl, openssl, lets-encrypt, archlinux

On 2021-09-30 [the Lets Encrypt certificate DST_ROOT_CA_X3 expired](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/). I have an older Archlinux build that is now failing basic https requests to Lets Encrypt domains.

For example: `curl -sv https://serverfault.com` yields:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://serverfault.com/
*   Trying 151.101.193.69...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to serverfault.com (151.101.193.69) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [108 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [4487 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
} [2 bytes data]
* SSL certificate problem: certificate rejected
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* Closing connection 0
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
} [2 bytes data]
```

[I have found other posts that describe how to remove this certificate on Ubuntu based builds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69407725/4396787). I am unfamiliar with Archlinux - how do you go about doing the same?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [ca-certificates](https://archlinux.org/packages/core/any/ca-certificates/) package which most likely just needs to be updated.

```
sudo pacman -Sy ca-certificates
```

or just update your entire system

```
sudo pacman -Syu
```